# DevExpress Grid view Query - DataSource property set to DataTable but showing incorrect number of Columns

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datatable, devexpress

I have a DataTable  which I use to bind to the my DevExpress GridView .

My DataTable is dynamic ie - sometimes it can bring 4 columns sometimes even 20. The problem is that when i first time set my GridView with the dataTable which has ,say ,at that time 20 columns, it will display properly , next time if my DataTable has only 4 columns, my GirdView will still Display all the 20 Columns with values in only the 4 columns which my DataTable has at that time.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Attached is ScreenShot.[image]

It is something to do with the clear of some memory instance / disposing off an object ? If so please help with the API for the DevExpress GridView.

**UPDATE**

this code calls set the datasource

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = dtBindToGridView; // MyDataTable
gcAnalysisTaskPermission.DataSource = bindingSource1; //My GridView 
bindingSource1.ResetBindings(true); // Reset the BindingSource
```

Thanks,

Mangesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `BindingSource`, try settin the `ResetBinding()`

```
public void SetData()
{
   //setting the datasource of your binding source
   myBindingSource.DataSource = GetMyDataTable(); 

   //after the datasource has been set, call this.
   //use true, because the metadata has changed
   myBindingSource.ResetBindings(true); 
}
```

**UPDATE**

according to [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q362180) you could try calling `PopulateColumns`

```
public void SetData()
{
   //setting the datasource of your binding source
   myBindingSource.DataSource = GetMyDataTable(); 

   gridView1.PopulateColumns();
}
```

Comment: bindingSource1.DataSource = dtBindToGridView; // MyDataTable

gcAnalysisTaskPermission.DataSource = bindingSource1;  //My GridView

bindingSource1.ResetBindings(true); // Reset the BindingSource

Comment: you could hide all blank columns after setting the datasource. But its a ugly solution...

Answer (score 3):

First of all try to reset the data source as below:

```
grid.DataSource = null;
grid.DataSource = GetData();
```

If  you have binding soucrce this does not work

Call [`gridView.PopulateColumns()`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_PopulateColumnstopic).